# How to get updated state from react parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following structure

=Parent Component (with a list as a state)

== Sub Comp list={list})

=== Sub Comp2 list={list}

==== Node list={list}

```
export const Node = (props) => {

// some state setup
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

const handleCheckbox = () => {
  if(!checked){
   //Checkbox checked, add this Node to list in Parent Component
   props.updateList(someLabel) 
  }
 else{
   props.removeFromList(someLabel)
 }
}

return( 
<TreeItem
icon = {<Checkbox checked={checked} onChange={handleCheckbox}}
> 
{expanded && !fetching ? childNodes : <TreeItem label="reached end" />
</TreeItem>

)

}
```

Now this work the way that I intended, but the problem is since it's a TreeView if I collapse and expand one of the parent nodes, I lose the checked value.

To fix this I put

```
useEffect(() => {

var inList = props.list.find(function(item) { return item.name === label} ) !=== undefined 

if(inList){ setChecked(true)} else{setChecked(false)}

}, [])
```

Now the above works as intended, but only if I go to the next page on my form and then come back. The problem is that when the list is updated, the useEffect is still using the old state of the list.

How do I force useEffect to use the most updated state, or force the state to update since it's asynchronous?

Comment: second param is `useEffect(fn, props)` specifies when to re-run the effect. In your code you have `[]` which will never re-run the effect. You need `[props.list]` because your effects needs to re-run when `list` gets updated

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options depending on your circumstance. If you just want the latest parent state in the child component you can pass the parent's state as well as the updater as a prop to the child component as below.

Parent:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <ChildComponent checked={checked} setChecked={setChecked} />
  )
}
```

Child:

```
const ChildComponent = ({checked, setChecked}) => {
  return (
  <>
    <p>{checked}</p>
    <button onClick={() =>setChecked(!checked)}>Button!</button>
  </>
  )
}
```

If you are trying to use the state information in parallel components or if you are passing state more than one or two levels down, consider using a context.